# Flip image vertically in C++ without external libraries like OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, image-processing, android-ndk

I have the following function which receives image as void*. How can I flip it upside down without using external libraries like OpenCV. Image width and height are known.

Note: this function will be called at least 30 times a second on Android so this needs to be efficient.

```
PushVideoFrame(void *bytes, int width, int height) {
    if (clientPtr == nullptr) {
        return ErrorCodes::DEVICE_CONNECTION;
    }

     char* data = static_cast< char *>(bytes);

     //////// CODE TO FLIP IMAGE /////////////

    clientPtr->PushVideoFrameAsync(data, width * height * 4)
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at OpenGL ES shader code for flipping? I would also check if the flipping can be done as a part of the image rendering pipeline (which I assume uses OpenGL ES).

Comment: This seems impossible to answer without knowing the encoding of the image data. For example, is it interleaved or planar? Is it compressed in some way? etc

Comment: you want a nested loop copying pixels around? because you said you did not want library recommendations. show us your attempt. this is expected. [tour], [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swap rows with additional memory:

```cpp
void flipVertically(uint8_t *data, int width, int height) {
    vector<uint8_t> temp(width);
    for (int i = 0; i < height / 2; i++) {
        void *ptr1 = data + i*width;
        void *ptr2 = data + (height-i-1)*width;
        
        // swap(row1, row2) with temp buffer
        memcpy(&temp[0], ptr1, width);
        memcpy(ptr1, ptr2, width);
        memcpy(ptr2, &temp[0], width);
    }
}
```